# How to use OpenSSL library without socket management?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openssl

I am improving an existing C++ communication module by adding full cryptographic functionality to it. I want to use the full functionality of OpenSSL like handshaking, key agreement, key generation and encryption to make the created channel between the server and the client secure.

My problem is, that I do not want to give up the existing socket-managing methods, and simply use OpenSSL for this task. My module must still be in control of the file descriptors, socket construction/destruction and message sending/receiving.

I was reading the source code of OpenSSL a lot lately, and I noticed it uses a state machine. The state machine initiates the construction and sending of messages like client hello for the handshaking. I have tried to figure out how I could prevent the statemachine from sending/receiving these messages, while still maintaining its functionality.

I noticed that OpenSSL uses a lot of function pointers which are found in ssl_method_st which stored in ssl_st structure.

```c
    /* Used to hold SSL/TLS functions */
    struct ssl_method_st {
        int version;
        unsigned flags;
        unsigned long mask;
        int (*ssl_new) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_clear) (SSL *s);
        void (*ssl_free) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_accept) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_connect) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_read) (SSL *s, void *buf, size_t len, size_t *readbytes);
        int (*ssl_peek) (SSL *s, void *buf, size_t len, size_t *readbytes);
        int (*ssl_write) (SSL *s, const void *buf, size_t len, size_t *written);
        int (*ssl_shutdown) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_renegotiate) (SSL *s);
        int (*ssl_renegotiate_check) (SSL *s, int);
        int (*ssl_read_bytes) (SSL *s, int type, int *recvd_type,
                               unsigned char *buf, size_t len, int peek,
                               size_t *readbytes);
        int (*ssl_write_bytes) (SSL *s, int type, const void *buf_, size_t len,
                                size_t *written);
        int (*ssl_dispatch_alert) (SSL *s);
        long (*ssl_ctrl) (SSL *s, int cmd, long larg, void *parg);
        long (*ssl_ctx_ctrl) (SSL_CTX *ctx, int cmd, long larg, void *parg);
        const SSL_CIPHER *(*get_cipher_by_char) (const unsigned char *ptr);
        int (*put_cipher_by_char) (const SSL_CIPHER *cipher, WPACKET *pkt,
                                   size_t *len);
        size_t (*ssl_pending) (const SSL *s);
        int (*num_ciphers) (void);
        const SSL_CIPHER *(*get_cipher) (unsigned ncipher);
        long (*get_timeout) (void);
        const struct ssl3_enc_method *ssl3_enc; /* Extra SSLv3/TLS stuff */
        int (*ssl_version) (void);
        long (*ssl_callback_ctrl) (SSL *s, int cb_id, void (*fp) (void));
        long (*ssl_ctx_callback_ctrl) (SSL_CTX *s, int cb_id, void (*fp) (void));
    };
```

Maybe I could somehow set some of these pointers to my own functions without calling SSL_set_fd to make it work? I expect OpenSSL to construct and encrypt the required messages like clientHello, serverHello whenever they are needed, but instead of sending it, giving the constructed message to my module.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using TLS for the communication protocol or something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I direct your attention [to the `BIO_new_bio_pair(3)` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_s_bio):

> One typical use of BIO pairs is to place TLS/SSL I/O under application
>   control, this can be used when the application wishes to use a non
>   standard transport for TLS/SSL or the normal socket routines are
>   inappropriate.

BIO is OpenSSL's input/output source/sink abstraction layer.

The brief example towards the end of the manual page seems to describe what you want to do perfectly. To summarize:

- Create a linked BIO pair
- Use `SSL_set_BIO()` to attach a new SSL session to one half of the BIO pair (instead of to a socket)
- Use the SSL session normally, and read/write TLS-encrypted data from the other BIO pair. You can take the data and handle reading/writing to the socket yourself, from this point, or do whatever you want with it.

The BIO pair forms, effectively, something quite analogous to a bi-directional pipe file descriptor. `BIO_new_bio_pair` gives you something along the lines of what you get from `pipe(2)`, except that both ends of the pipe are bi-directional.

One thing you have to be very careful about, and understand, is the semantics of the data getting buffered internally, in the internal "BIO pipe", and how to correctly deal with it. For example, SSL-level routines will now mostly behave as if they are connected to a non-blocking file descriptor, and behave accordingly, when there's no data in the underlying "BIO pipe", or its the internal buffer is full.

Comment: I am still not sure how this is going to work. I will try to explain how I understand it. Correct me please!

On connection a client hello message will be sent from openSSL to my client module through this bio_pair, which I can forward to the server. My server will send this message to its own openSSL module, which is going to respond with a server hello which can be forwarded to the client. If I want to send my own message the bio_pair is not needed, since I can encrypt/decrypt those messages like in this link: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption.

Comment: This is mostly correct, except no "messages" are sent via the bio_pairs. What is sent in and out of them are an opaque, encrypted bytestream. You cannot make any more sense out of that data than anyone else attempting to MITM an SSL/TLS connection. The only thing you can to do it is forward it to some other source/sink of SSL/TLS encrypted data. Whether it's a real, native, SSL/TLS perior, or another facade that grabs the encrypted data and pushes it through bio pairs on its side, is immaterial.